# Border around bootstrap container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a container that contains two rows. I want there to be a border around the container (not between the two rows). When I tried to set a border around the container, it gave me a border between the two rows - not sure what I should be doing differently here.

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="border:1px solid #cecece;"  
    <div class="row">                                           
      <!-- Need to add theme, buttons -->                       
      <div class="col-xs-12"> Text here </div>          
    </div>                                                      
    <div class="row">                                           
      <!-- Need to add theme, buttons -->                       
      <div class="col-xs-12"> Buttons here </div>               
    </div>                                                      
</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code is **almost** perfectly fine.

Look at first line of it - `>` is missing.

See working example below.

http://jsfiddle.net/864cw2fn/

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="border:1px solid #cecece;">  
    <div class="row">                                           
          <!-- Need to add theme, buttons -->                       
        <div class="col-xs-12"> Text here </div>          
    </div>                                                      
        <div class="row">                                           
          <!-- Need to add theme, buttons -->                       
        <div class="col-xs-12"> Buttons here </div>               
        </div>                                                      
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. When you post a fixed block of code can you please highlight and explain the changes you've made? (I hadn't spotted it until I read the other answer!)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid table-bordered">
    <div class="row">                                           
          <!-- Need to add theme, buttons -->                       
        <div class="col-xs-12"> Text here </div>          
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).